# Native splash screen image not working on flutter (Android)

Tags: flutter

So im trying to display a custom splash screen image in my flutter app.But for some reason the background color as well and the custom image are not showing up

**path where I am editing  app/src/main/res/drawable**

**launch_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

[image]

No matter how may times I try its not changing ,I'm a newbie to flutter any guidance will be really helpful

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen

Comment: Following the above link, Any idea why the current setup is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

you should try with this

```
<item
        android:height="200dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

That's work for me.

Comment: For bitmap you should use .xml file

Answer (score 0):

replacing `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />` with         `android:drawable="@mipmap/launcher_icon"` in `..\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21\launch_background.xml` file worked for me